# How can I get rid of an accidentally recorded animation

Tags: animation, error

I have apparently accidentally recorded some editing I made to my project.
I know I sometimes inadvertently hit the space bar while doing some editing to my scene. Until now, I was unaware that it could cause problems later on.
Now, I have this Oktoberfest scene I'm working on that involves some mugs of beer. I have made some particles emitters to generate bubbles in the liquid.
It worked fine when I was only animating one beer mug sitting on the 'floor'. But then I added a character (imported from DAZ), made many copies of the mug and experimented with positioning the character and the mugs.

THE PROBLEM occurred when I decided to hit the space bar to start the animation and generate some bubbles for a preliminary render before tweaking the lights and textures.

There were bubbles all over the place and objects appearing and disappearing, being moved randomly.

I tried to edit the animation but there is nothing to be seen there, no keyframes, no 'action' that I can select or delete.

Is there a way to 'reset' the animation completely or save the blend file without the animation data?

I can redo all the particle systems to correct what's going wrong, but that wouldn't solve the randomly moving props.

Here are just a few frames to illustrate the problem.[First frame with particle emitters selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn9vj.jpg)

[image: Frame with bubbles being emitted away from the emitters]

[image: Frame with a mug appearing at a previous place]

[image: Frame with two mugs displaced]

Answer (score 1):

Yuo have Auto Keying turned on. This will insert keyframes every time you move an object and then move to another frame. Click it to uncheck it then select <kbd>A</kbd>ll your objects in Object mode, hover over the timeline and hit <kbd>X</kbd> > <kbd>⌦ Delete Keyframes</kbd> to clear the lot and start again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks John,
I thought I would be off the hook easy with that but it didn't work.
I Unchecked the blue 'Auto Keying' button, selected everything in my scene and put my mouse cursor over the 'Timeline', clicked 'X', selected 'Deleted Keyframes'. 
Nothing happened.
I played the sequence from frame '0' and all is the same.

Comment: I think you'll have to provide access to your blend file in that case so that others here with more knowledge of animation than me can have a look. If it's not too large you can share it via: https://blend-exchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks again John, but my blend file is too big for blend-exchange.
I made some changes in my Beer mug file. I'll try to delete all the mugs that are in the scene now and append a new one to see if all the moving history of those mugs in the timeline will disappear with them.

Comment: I wondered about that. Although it's preferred that you upload to the official site lots of folk put their files on, for example, Google Drive or similar and post a link to it in the question.

Comment: I've looked for free options to share that blend file but I couldn't find any that would accept a 100+Mb file.
I'd need to work on the meshes and textures to make it smaller, but that is a process I am not yet very familiar or comfortable with.
Remeshing, un-subdividing and all methods to lower polycounts. The textures I used are already only of 1 or 2k resolution. Unless those imported with the character from DAZ are heavier. That I don't know.
So I went with the 'scratch the mugs and start over from there solution'.
(I'll have to be careful not to accidently hit the spacebar though.)

Answer (score 0):

Just an update.
I went through the process of deletion of the guilty mugs and re-appending and repositioning copies of the said mug from frame one.
It worked. No more unexpected ghost appearances in the timeline.
Lot of work though.
I which there had been an easier way.
In short:
Since there was no keyframe recorded, none could be selected to delete them.
Deleting the objects referenced in those inadvertently recorded moves effectively deleted the 'reference' as well.